# create a folder once a button click in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, directory, create-directory

I'm creating asp.net mvc 5 application.In that application I want generate a Folder once I click a button on front end view page.

I want to generate that folder with in following location `~/Essential_Folder/`

```
<input type = "button" value="Create_Folder" class="btn btn-default" id="create_folder"/>
```

How can I do this ,

1. can I do this using Server side language (in my case its C#), if its how ?
2. is this possible to do using client side language (such as JavaScript) ?

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     $('btn-default').click(function () {


     });

  </script>
```

Comment: You need to handle the buttons `.click()` event and use ajax to call a controller method that creates the folder.

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's actually a server side. Because there is no way a javascript or jquery can *actually* create file/folder in windows due to security. So why not directly make button hit the controller action to create directory!

Comment: @dotnetkid, That exactly what my comment was stating

Comment: @StephenMuecke so I should look at "create a folder using ajax in asp.net mvc" Is it ?

Comment: The controller code just needs to use the [System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) method (and return a `JsonResult` to indicate sucess or otherwise which you can test in the ajax success callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Stephen mentioned, you need to use ajax in order to create a folder. So you can have an action method like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CreateDirectory()
    {
        //if location has folder called "Essential_Folder" it should allow to goto inside of this if condition
        if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Essential_Folder/")))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Content/Essential_Folder/NewDir_{0}",
            DateTime.Now.Millisecond)));
            return Json("OK");
        }
        return Json("NO");
    }
```

And your ajax call should something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.btn').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("CreateDirectory")",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response === 'OK')
                    alert("Directory has been created");
                else
                    alert("errro");
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Since the call making modifications, it probably should be a POST rather than a GET (would not want users to be able to navigate to it)

Comment: Don't use `Server.MapPath` twice for a same location.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi  thanks I'm trying to integrate this solution , Here I have additional question , If we want to create new folder ,  should we create inside `~/Content` location ?

Comment: It's common to store your files and folders inside `~/Content`, but you can also use `~/Essential_Folder/`

Comment: @SirwanAfifi But long time ago , in mvc 4 application I created folder manually inside Root location , then I deployed that project using IIS manager ,but then that folder disappeared , I thought that why you refer that location

Comment: @Mr.Wolf you said `Don't use Server.MapPath twice for a same location` ??